# Swift CoreData child to-many entities not accessible through parent

Tags: ios, swift, nsmanagedobject

I have an `event` parent entity which contains many `fight`s. All the `fight` entries have the proper `event` inverse property id. I can access the `event` through the `fight`, but when I try to get the `fight`s by accessing `event.fights` I get the following error

```
expression produced error: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-5)..
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

Warning: hit breakpoint while running function, skipping commands and conditions to prevent recursion.Warning: hit breakpoint while running function, skipping commands and conditions to prevent recursion.Warning: hit breakpoint while running function, skipping commands and conditions to prevent recursion.
```

Why can't I access the many child properties through the parent? Is there any way to fix this?

The type shows up as an `_ArrayBuffer<Schedule.Fight>`

**Edit 1:**

After searching more on the subject, it turns out this is the result of something called relationship faults, which is a performance enhancement meaning that the child entities are lazily loaded.

I still couldn't find any solution on how to solve this and make the `child` entities accessible. Most answers seem to rely on the an `NSSet` however, my child entites are defined as optional arrays as so:

```
extension Event {
...
@NSManaged public var arena: String
@NSManaged public var baseTitle: String
@NSManaged public var eventFights: [EventFight]?
...
}
```

Can this be fixed by adding something to the fetch request or maybe forcing data loading on child entities? Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Core Data to-many relationship must be an (unordered) **set**, it cannot be an array, and I recommended to declare to-many relationships always as non-optional:

```
@NSManaged public var eventFights: Set<Event>
```

Comment: This helped, thanks a lot. I did have the array as non-optional at first but then I was just stuck trying different things. I don't know why the stub xcode generated for was with an array instead of set but this solved it, thank you!